# Understand step in computing marginal distribution of restricted Boltzmann Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, proof-writing

Proof taken from http://image.diku.dk/igel/paper/AItRBM-proof.pdf (page 24)

I understand everything up to and including:

(1)

$$p(\textbf{v}) = \frac{1}{Z}e^{\sum_{j=1}^mb_jv_j} \prod_{i=1}^n\sum e^{h_i(c_i + \sum_{h_i}w_{ij}v_j)}$$

My question is how do we go from (1) to (2):

(2)

$$p(\textbf{v}) = \frac{1}{Z}\prod_{j=1}^m e^{b_jv_j}\prod_{i=1}^n(1+e^{c_i+\sum_{j=1}^m})$$.

(I see where $\frac{1}{Z}\prod_{j=1}^m e^{b_jv_j}$ comes from but not the rest of the formula.)

Also, how easy would it be to extend this to multi-class? (Currently, ($\textbf{v,h}$) $\in \{ 0,1\}^{m+n}$).

Comment: Let us start from the correct text, that is, in (1), from $\displaystyle\sum\limits_h\prod\limits_i$ instead of your $\displaystyle\prod\limits_i\sum\limits_h,$ then, is there still a problem?

Comment: @Did long story, short: yes. How do we know that $e^h_i$ sums to 1? -- which is the only way I see of using arriving at (2).

Comment: @Did sorry, but from the text it looks like it is supposed to be product, then sum; not sum, then product.

Comment: No. Simply read (22) on page 24.

Comment: @Did mmm... I did. I see a product, then a sum; not the reverse. Am I just seeing things?

Comment: Only at the penultimate line, and this is not relevant, is it? // Anyway, after two comments and an answer, I feel I did everything I could to explain to you your mistake. My advice: read slowly my answer.

Comment: This one is TRIVIAL once you read my answer, it simply says that $$\sum_{h_i=0}^1\mathrm e^{h_it_i}=1+\mathrm e^{t_i}.$$ See? You are not the only one who can yell...

Comment: ((Amusing: some transient comment by the OP.))

Answer (score 0):

*Algebraic fact:* For every collection $(t_i)_{i\in I}$,
$$
\sum_h\prod_{i\in I}\mathrm e^{h_it_i}=\prod_{i\in I}\sum_{\ell=0}^1\mathrm e^{\ell t_i}=\prod_{i\in I}(1+\mathrm e^{t_i}),
$$
where the sum on the LHS runs over every $h=(h_i)_{i\in I}$ in $\{0,1\}^I$.

Comment: thanks. but is there a sketch of proof of this.

Comment: Everything works here, for example a recursion over $I$, or, to start from the RHS and to expand it.