# Understanding an algebraic fact that involves summations and products

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I'm struggling with understanding an algebraic fact or a trick. I don't know if there is a name or a definition for it. I can only give you an example of it:

Let $n, m \in \Bbb N$ and $x \in \Bbb R$ then:

$$ \sum^{n}\stackrel{(m)}{\cdots} \sum^{n} \prod^m x=  \sum^{n} x \stackrel{(m)}{\cdots}\sum^{n} x = \prod^m \left(\sum^{n} x\right) $$

To make sure that it is true, I sketched an example by giving $n=2, m=3, x=1$ and everything was correct. But I'm still struggling to understand why it is true! I am unfortunately unable to understand it. Can someone please explain it to me in easy words and examples? Please try to use as little math notation as possible since I'm not a math guru!

Edit: does these facts even have a name or something? are they known? maybe called 'factorizations'?

Edit: yes it is a trick. I came across this in a paper. This OP in this question [Understand step in computing marginal distribution of restricted Boltzmann Distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867146/understand-step-in-computing-marginal-distribution-of-restricted-boltzmann-distr) wanted to as basically the same thing but couldn't summarize the ideas/tricks in the formulation in the paper linked in his question. I'm reading the same paper.

Comment: You are going to be more precise. None of that makes any sense.

Comment: Is it a trick question? Since a products of ones get you one (so first equality) the second one comes from the fact the sums seem independent ?

Comment: @Chinny84 yes it is a trick

Comment: What? So you didn't want an answer?

Comment: @GPerez of course I do!

Comment: @JackTwain I've touched up the question a bit to make it clearer, make sure I haven't changed the meaning of it.

Answer (score 1):

The "trick" is using the distributive property of multiplication over a sum and the commutative property of multiplication. First, `as many summations as m` is better written as $\sum^n\stackrel {(m)}{\cdots}\sum^n$. Also, to simplify, write $\prod^mx = x^m = p$. The left hand expression, then, is: $$\sum^n\stackrel {(m)}{\cdots}\sum^np = p\sum^n\stackrel {(m)}{\cdots}\sum^n1 \quad \text{(distributive)}\\ = pn^m$$
The right hand side, in contrast, is: $$\prod^m\sum^nx = \prod^mx\sum^n1 \quad \text{(distributive)}\\ =\prod^mxn = (xn)^m = x^mn^m \quad \text{(commutative)} \\ = pn^m$$

In effect, what you're basically saying is $$n^mx^m = (xn)^m $$

in the case that $n,m$ are natural. Verbally, "you can  multiply a number by itself $m$ times, and sum the result $n^m$ times, or you can add a number to itself $n$ times, and multiply the result by itself $m$ times, and the final result will be the same".